# Why does the following Python code not delete columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please advise guys?

I´m trying to append data from multiple sheets in 1 Excel file and there is plenty of unnecessary columns that I want to get rid of. After checking multiple threads I compiled the below code for this purpose however it returns error :

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/Python379/XY.py", line 13, in 
data.drop(columns,axis=1,inplace=True)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'drop'*

The code should :
1 - load data from the selected sheets
2 - delete the unnecessary columns
3 - create new column to show sheet names

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\XY\XY\XY.xlsm",sheet_name=['Boston', 'NY','Tampa'],header=4)
df = pd.DataFrame()

columns = ["Unnamed: 10", "Unnamed: 12", "Unnamed: 14","Unnamed: 15","Unnamed: 16","Unnamed: 17"]

data.drop(columns,axis=1,inplace=True)

for name, frame in data.items():
    frame['sheet'] = name
    df = df.append(frame)
    
print(df)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably because you have multiple sheets that form separate dfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `sheet_name=['Boston', 'NY','Tampa']` you are creating a dictionary of dataframes, not a dataframe, so `drop` will not work on a dictionary. You have to iterate through the dictionary(https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/) and for each dataframe you must use `drop`. I hope that makes sense.

You may find the information about the `sheet_name` in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Thank you, makes sense! I´ll try to figure out something :)

Comment: @tomecsek If you think this answer helped you, please accept it/give it a thumb up :)